# Are LRC (Longitudinal Redundancy Check) or CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check) of any use in modern day computing?

Tags: hash, crc, checksum

I am currently learning about the history of **Data integrity** / **Error detection**.

In the old days of tape drives, *LRC* was used for error detection. They were also used (at certain point in time) for ensuring data integrity. But nowadays, the work that *CRC* or *LRC* did, has been mostly replaced by Hashes (`MD5`, `SHA1` etc).

My questions are:

- What were some of the reasons, why CRC or LRC was replaced by Message Digests?
- Are these methods (LRC & CRC) still applicable/safe in modern day computing?

**P.S.:** I am asking this question from a cryptographic/Computer Security standpoint.

Comment: CRC32  is used in the gzip file format. I suppose you do count that?

Comment: @JohnDvorak for what purpose is it used for in CRC32?

Comment: You mean what purpose CRC32 serves in GZIP? It's a consistency check for the compressed data. You can also have a separate CRC16 just for the file header.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Thanks for sharing this info

Comment: Checksums have no cryptographic value. In general, they are useful for connection errors - and completely useless against thinking adversaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What were some of the reasons, why CRC or LRC was replaced by Message Digests?

Well, a CRC has a lot of mathematical structure.  This structure is useful to prove certain things about it (for example, if we get a 'burst error' that is limited to a region no longer than the length of the CRC, then the CRC will *always* detect it).  On the other hand, this same mathematical structure is also useful for an attacker (assuming he knows the CRC polynomial); for example, given $CRC(M)$, the attacker can deduce which bits of $M$ he has to flip to make the CRC be any predetermined value, and this is true even if the attacker doesn't know the actual value of $M$ (!).

We really don't care to give the attacker this level of control, and hence we use Message Digests instead, which are designed specifically so that if any bit of the message changes, then the attacker can't guess what the updated MAC would be.

Comment: +1 can you please elaborate a little bit on your first paragraph. I understood what you are trying to convey, but your notations like **M** or **CRC(M)** are kind of confusing to me. So i would appreciate if you can elaborate on that, and make it a lot more intuitive!!

Comment: @VasuDeo.S: $M$ is the message, $CRC(M)$ is the computed CRC of the message...

Comment: hashes of a file could be displayed publicly (as they are one way function, so no problem of reversibility). Is $CRC(M)$ also public, or is it treated like a key? By that i mean, is it possible to get a clue on $PT$ using $CRC(M)$ or, is it same like a hash (where no guess on the $PT$ could be made just by viewing its hash)

Comment: @VasuDeo.S: when we're doing integrity checking of a communication link (e.g. TLS), we generally assume that the adversary has access to the integrity tag.  In any case, the CRC would also allow the attacker to modify $M$ in such as way to leave $CRC(M)$ unmodified, and so just hiding the CRC doesn't actually stop attacks.

Comment: So in a CRC system, the attacker can modify the $M$, in such a way that it will still correspond to the same $CRC$ checksum? Like, is it possible for different $M$ to have the same checksum in $CRC$ system?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S: of course it's possible; $M$ can be arbitrarily long, while the $CRC$ is a fixed size; if $M$ is longer than $CRC$, then we'll always have multiple $M$'s that correspond to the same $CRC$.  The same holds for a cryptographical MAC - the distinction is that, for a MAC, the attacker has no way of *finding* those collisions...

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. BTW what are you thoughts on the second point of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I still see some uses of CRC in the case of encrypted protocols.
The secure parts are embedding hashes and/or MACs in a data field, then it checks the integrity of the whole message a second time with an extremely lighter algorithm (CRC).

This way in embedded cryptography with high speed, you avoid yourself cryptographical computation if the transmission failed and the CRC/LRC is wrong.

Anyway, if you don't look at performances and don't work with microcontrollers, you're right it should desappear behind modern hash and MACs.

Comment: So, are these nowadays used more like a addon feature over hashes/MAC rather then standalone by themselves?

Comment: Yeah, light addons. It's too easy to forge-attack and should not be used in standalone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit puzzled with your P.S., in my understanding LRC/CRC were never designed with security in mind, so it's unclear how shall your second part of the question be interpreted...

Both are still widely used because they are an integral part of a huge number of well-established protocols and standards. To name a few: TCP/IP packets checksums, magnetic stripe on your credit card, message exchange between a contactless card and a reader, asynchronous protocols used for financial transactions (especially, over a phone line) and many more..

But security has never been their purpose.